# Azure Storage CloudFile custom MetaData API like Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

Is there an API for the Azure Storage CloudFile to allow custom metadata.

The MS Tool Azure Storage Explorer has this custom metadata feature available for CloudFile in the FileShare Azure Storage Service.

[image: Existing MS Tool Metadata Editor]

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFile  Custom MetaData feature wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var file = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("abc.txt");

// Populates a file's properties and metadata, which triggers a request to Azure File Storage.
file.FetchAttributes();

// Adds new key value pairs into metadata, which is a client-only change.
file.Metadata.Add("Key1", "Value1");
file.Metadata.Add("Key2", "Value2");

// Updates the file's metadata, which triggers a request to Azure File Storage.
file.SetMetadata();
```

Comment: The above example code also works on a CloudFile ref before you write the file as in when you do a first time create.  Also – The “Value1” “Value2” Value cannot be blank, check your value before you call the Metadata.  I presume the Update concept is similar.   The above code is very helpful thank you – the following from MS was not clear that it was modifiable in Azure and would persist…   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.metadata?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Yes, metadata can also be specified during creation. :)